# % units in SVG animations seem to be relative to both the parent and to itself?

Tags: css, svg

I have two different inline SVGs in my HTML, and both of them have their child  elements animated to translate across the viewport. Both `<svg>` elements have a width equal to the viewport width. For the first animation, I used percentage units to do this and finished it successfully. For the second one, I tried the same thing and it wasn't working properly. Upon further research, I learned that when descendants of an `<svg>` element use percent units, the percent is relative to the descendants size, and not the parent.

This is puzzling to me, because I successfully animated the first one using percentages. When I used `transform:translateX(100%)` on a `<path>` in the first svg, it translated across the entire screen. When I did it to a `<path>` on the second svg, it only translated a distance equal to its own width.

What could be causing this discrepancy? Has anyone encountered a similar issue before?

Comment: I think this would be much clearer if you [provided some examples](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). Percentage units in SVG are relative to the <svg> container element.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The SVG specification describes exactly how percentage units work.  But it may depend on exactly what your SVGs are doing. How are we supposed to help you debug SVGs that we cannot see for ourselves?  Please read the following article and update your question: [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here I animate a `<rect>` and a `<path>`. In this setup they behave the same.

```css
@keyframes move {
  from { transform: translateX(0%); }
  to { transform: translateX(80%); }
}

rect {
  animation: 3s forwards move;
}

path {
  animation: 3s 1s forwards move;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" fill="navy"/>
  <path d="M10 40 a 10 10 0 1 1 1 0" fill="orange"/>
</svg>
```

Maybe you have a discrepancy between the size of the SVG and how it is displayed. In the example below you can see that I specify 100% for the SVG (instead of the videBox), but the elements only moves for 80% like the first example. The size of the element in the first makes it appear that thy go all the way to the right, where as the second example the smaller size of the element does not "reach" the end (and the SVG is still 100%).

```css
@keyframes move {
  from { transform: translateX(0%); }
  to { transform: translateX(80%); }
}

rect {
  animation: 3s forwards move;
}

path {
  animation: 3s 1s forwards move;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" fill="navy"/>
  <path d="M10 40 a 10 10 0 1 1 1 0" fill="orange"/>
</svg>
```